# Set unzip location in Chocolatey Package Install Arguments

Tags: windows-10, powershell, zip, chocolatey

I'm trying to install a Chocolatey package which is essentially a `zip` archive from Github repository releases. Is it possible to set a custom unzip path in a manner similar to `choco install zippedpackage --ia "unzippath=D:\path\"`?

For example, I've managed to set a custom install location for `MSI` (WiX, `INSTALL_ROOT`), `Inno Setup` (`/DIR`) and `NSIS` (`/D`) installers. But how to do it for `zip`?

There is an article on [Install-ChocolateyZipPackage](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-zip-package) describing an `-UnzipLocation <String>` option, but I don't know if it is possible to set it from `choco install` command.

Comment: Are you facing any limitations when using the Powershell cmdlet?

Comment: @Smeerpijp no, I'm doing it on my own machine.

Answer (score 1):

Install-ChocolateyZipPackage accepts an optional [-UnzipLocation parameter](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-zip-package#unziplocation-string).

```
$unzipLocation = '{0}\Some\Path' -f $Env:SystemDrive

$packageArgs = @{
  ...
  unzipLocation = $unzipLocation
}

Install-ChocolateyZipPackage @packageArgs
```